# Removing edges from NetworkX graph which are NOT in a set

Tags: networkx

I have an almost tree-like graph with one special node which serves as the root and a bunch of terminal nodes which are the leaves. The graph has some small loops which are artifacts from a previous function and I need to remove them.

To do this, I have performed a `nx.dijkstra_path` between the root node and every terminal node. I then convert the traversed nodes into tuples representing edges and store them in a set:

```
traversed_edges = set()
for terminal_node in terminal_nodes:
    dijkstra_res = nx.dijkstra_path(graph, root_node, terminal_node, weight="length")
    for n_idx in range(len(dijkstra_res)-1):
        traversed_edges.add((dijkstra_res[n_idx], dijkstra_res[n_idx+1]))
```

I have to use this instead of a depth-first search because I want to use a weight, which doesn't seem possible any other way.

At this point I want to remove all edges which have NOT been traversed, which would make the graph into a proper tree. I try to do this like so:

```
graph.remove_edges_from(graph.edges - traversed_edges)
```

This statement executes successfully, but it has deleted edges seemingly at random. It's worth noting that this graph currently has many "psuedonodes", i.e. nodes that are just connecting two edges. Really, every long line is composed of lots of little short lines end-to-end.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

But what I find most perplexing is that if I remove the traversed edges, then I am indeed left with the edges that were definitely not traversed, as seen below, which is the result of executing:

```
graph.remove_edges_from(traversed_edges)
```

[image]

Why is it that removing the traversed edges successfully leaves me with all the edges that I want to delete, but removing the inverse just garbles the graph?

Comment: Why don't you create a new graph just with the traversed edges?

Comment: Indeed, I realized that I could do that a bit later and that did solve my problem, but the behaviour described in this post does seem outright wrong, I think I will report it as a potential bug to the networkx developers.

Comment: `graph.edges` is not an instance of `set`. Your expression `graph.edges - traversed_edges` is hence nonsensical and does not return the result you are expecting. Hence the "bug".

Comment: Indeed they are different types but the statement does execute successfully and have an effect. And when I did the opposite, the result was not nonsensical. So I think it really does qualify as a bug, or at the very least, erratic behaviour which should be mitigated